# How to get all data from a struct?

Tags: matlab, struct

I've got a result from a web service and MatLab gladly notifies that it is a *1x1 struct*. However, when I try to display it (by typing *receivedData* and pressing <kbd>enter</kbd>) I get to see this:

```
ResponseData: [5x1 struct]
```

Equally gladly, I entered the following, in my attempt to get the data viewed to me:

```
struct2array(responseData)
```

I get only a bunch (not five, more than five) of strings that **might** be names headers of columns of the data provided.

How do I get **all** the data from such structure?

Answer (score 4):

You may use `fieldnames` to get the data from the struct and then iteratively display the data using `getfield` function. For example:

```
structvariable = struct('a',123,'b',456,'c',789);
dataout = zeros(1,length(structvariable)) % Preallocating data for structure
field = fieldnames(a);

for i = 1:length(structvariable)
    getfield(structvariable,field{i})
end
```

Remember, `getfield` gives data in form of **cell**, not **matrix**.

Comment: But what about a data structure that I don't know what it looks like? I'd like a generic method for getting data out of such structures. For instance, how do I iterate and display **all** the values in the structure? I know how to do such operations in Java but MatLab scares me a bit.

Comment: The method I provide can give you all values of the structure, because it iterates all fields inside of structure. `fieldnames` is used to get all the field names of the struct, and `getfield` gets all the data in the specific field of the struct.

Answer (score 3):

or you can use cellfun function:

```
% STRUCT - your structure
% tmp_nam - structure field names
% tmp_val - values for structure field names


tmp_nam = fieldnames(STRUCT);
tmp_val = cellfun(@(x)(STRUCT.(x)),tmp_nam,'UniformOutput',false);
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to *display* all elements and subelements of a structure there is a custom function that you can download here:
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/13831-structure-display

Answer (score 0):

Some useful access syntax:

```
someVar = ResponseData(1)  %Displays the first element
someVar = ResponseData(4)  %Displays the 4th element
```

To display them all, one after the next

```
for ix = 1:length(ResponseData)
    tmp = ResponseData(ix);
end
```

To get all the fieldnames

```
names = fieldnames(ResponseData)
```

To get all 5 data elements from the structure with the first field names, and put them into a cell array

```
ixFieldName = 1;
someCellArray = {  ResponseData.(ixFieldName{1})  }
```

Answer (score 0):

A small correction to Sahinsu's answer:

```
structvariable = struct('a',123,'b',456,'c',789);
dataout = zeros(1,length(structvariable)) % Preallocating data for structure
field = fieldnames(structvariable);

for i = 1:length(field)
    getfield(structvariable,field{i})
end
```